# How to run CRON job in magneto 2

Tags: magento2, crontab

My custom CRON job not working automatically, but if I run it using command line then it is working.

I created basic module and below is my code for CRON job

crontab.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="cron_example" instance="companyname\modulename\Cron\Example" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Comment: are you on local host ?

Comment: No, I am on live server

Comment: cron is working i.e send email and newsletter ?

Comment: are they trigger by cron, not sure need to check.
my cron is working using command line, then why it is not working automatically, do i need to configure somewhere

Comment: if you set cron, your module cron will work automatically

Comment: please check: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: I gone through document, my understanding is, I can create Custom job code to run cron at specific time, after creating new cron group it is visible in admin section, I can set time but again its not executing

Answer (score 0):

When you have magerun2 installed you can run the following command:

> magerun2 sys:cron:run

Now you get a list of available cronjobs and if your job is configured correctly it should be shown and then you can use the key number to trigger it.

More informatief about how to install or use magerun2 can be found here:

> https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Comment: is magerun2 custom extension

Comment: The answer has been updated with more information

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but as I scheduled my job in Magento as

 <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
why it is not running automatically, it is working if I run it from command line